# reactnavigation stack prevents android and safari addressbar from hiding with scroll in pwa

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, progressive-web-apps

I'm exporting my project for the web using expo with reactnavigation v6 for PWA

my stack navigation is like this

```
  <NavigationContainer
          ref={(c) => {
            this._NavigationContainer = c;
          }}
          theme={{ colors: { background: "#ffffff" } }}
          linking={linking}
        >
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Homenavigator">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Homenavigator"
              component={Homenavigator}
              options={{
                header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => {
                  return <Header options={options} navigation={navigation} />;
                },
                headerStyle: {
                  height: 52,
                },
                headerMode:'float'
              }}
            />
          <Stack.Screen
              name="Page"
              component={Page}
              options={{
                header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => {
                  return (
                    <Header
                      options={options}
                      navigation={navigation}
                      pkey="page"
                    />
                  );
                },
                headerStyle: {
                  height: 52,
                },
                headerMode:'float',
              }}
            />
</Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

when I'm navigating to the "page" screen scroll works fine, which means when I scroll to the top or bottom of the page android chrome address bar is auto-hiding

but when I'm on the Homenavigator screen it doesn't and It is always stays

my page class is rendering something like this

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>{this.render_page_content()}</ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
```

the style for the container is

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#EFF1F5",
  },
```

my Homenavigator class is rendering a flatlist inside of a view

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#D00A30" /> // data loading indicator
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            ref={this.props.scrollRef}
            style={styles.homewidgets}
            data={this.state.homewidgets} // widget data
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.type + "-" + index}
            renderItem={({ item }) => this._render_homewidget_items(item)} // render widget data
            bounces={false}
            alwaysBounceVertical={false}
            snapToOffsets={[0, 76]} // snap for searchbox
            snapToAlignment="center"
            decelerationRate={"fast"}
            snapToEnd={false}
            onScroll={(e) => this.Homewidgets_onScroll(e)} // show topbar search when snaped to search box
            onMomentumScrollEnd={(e) => this.Homewidgets_onScroll(e)} // show topbar search when snaped to search box
            stickyHeaderIndices={[1]} // make a shadow widget sticky to use as topbar shadow
          />
        )}
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
```

the style for the container is

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#EFF1F5",
  },
```

I have been trying to fix this issue for some time now but I can't wrap my head around it

both my PWA and API have valid SSL certifications

I also set the display to "fullscreen" in the PWA manifest and it works fine when the user installed the app but I want this issue to fix even when the user is not installing my app

here are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "expo": "^42.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "1.1.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-sideswipe": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1"
  },
```

**edit**
I was messing around to fix this issue myself and notice a couple of things

- this issue only happens if you use bottom-tabs in stack navigations or nested stack navigation
- removing the position absolute from PWA style and replacing it with relative fixed the issue completely but broke all other styles because there is no class name to access specific nodes

if anyone facing the same issue and wants to debug it could be hard to test because you need to run it in the emulator and android browser so here is how I did it

I installed chrome with ADB command on my android emulator

then I access the localhost with my local IP and expo port number in the android emulator